# CSS Horizontal Menu float left loosing background color

Tags: html, css

In the following code, why does the `ul` element loose its background color when the child elements are floated?

I remember reading something about floats causing this, but I cannot remember.

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mf4dg4o0/))

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #036;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/  Basically, parent element collapse... quick fix: set height to ul...

Comment: The answer you selected as correct is actually a very bad hack way of fixing this issue. You should use the information in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am a noob to CSS so i didnt know better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The background color is there.  But you can't see it because it is behind the li tags.  To see that its there you can add a height tag to the ul attribute and then you will see the background.

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #036;
  height: 40px;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

To solve this properly you can add a clearfix class to the UL tag and add the following CSS

```
.clearfix {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This is so wrong, view the linked duplicate to see how it should be done.